# Sync Redmine to another Redmine?

Tags: synchronization, redmine

Our company uses Redmine to track tech support issues, but sometimes these issues are escalated to the outsourced development team, who has their own Redmine.

Has anyone ever found/written a sync between the two, so that a pair of issues can be synced: a change in A creates a change in B. I can't seem to find any guidance via Google.

These two Redmine installations are on separate webservers with separate databases.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve your goal you must use the REST API of the Redmine. You can write a script to sync them. You could make to sync two Redmine servers in minutes without writing a single line of code. There is service called Zapier that makes it easy to connect a web service to another web service seamlessly with a lot of options. You should check it out: http://zpr.io/gmXF

Answer (score 1):

I had a client asking about this and the only way we could think to do it was to create a plugin to send issues back and forth using the REST API. We haven't started the project yet so there isn't anything I can share about it.

Comment: My thought was that if I could acquire access to both DBs directly I could do it using scheduled MySQL routines. Any red flags I should be wary of?

Comment: You will need to be careful of changes happening while syncing. e.g. SiteA adds new issue at the same time as SiteB.

Comment: Also consider any attachments saved to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple sync using Redmine Java API http://code.google.com/p/redmine-java-api

There's an application, which can load data from one Redmine and save to another one - http://taskadapter.com , but it only supports interactive (manual) sync, no "daemon syncs".

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility might be Ruby Replicate: http://www.rubyrep.org/screencast.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is possible but if Email configuration is set in such a way that when an issue created/updated on first machine would be sent to the e-mail configuration setup in the second machine which receives the mail and generates/updates the issue on the second server.

You can refer this page to [create issue using email settings](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration)

Also production server settings can be set to the following:

```
production:   email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: smtp.domain.com 
      port: 25
      domain: domain.com
      enable_starttls_auto: false  
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "redminesendreceive@domain.com"
      password: "password"
```

These settings are also in the above create issue using email settings link.